# Not able to start Minikube - with HyperV

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, minikube

I have been consistently getting above error, I am not able to understand what's wrong when it was working till date. I tried in powershell with following command no luck `@(Get-Module -ListAvailable hyper-v).Name | Get-Unique`

But I can see Hyper-v enabled and can see by navigating Hyper-v manager window.

[image]

```
System Info:
Minikube version 1.12.3
Windows powershell exists
Hyper-V enabled
WSL2 installed on Windows 10 OS
```

[image]

When I execute below command in PowerShell I get below response

Whereas when I try executing command `Get-Module -Name Hyper-V -ListAvailable` no output available.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> @(Get-Command Get-VM).ModuleName
Hyper-V
```

Comment: try `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell` to install the missing powershell module. afterwards you may run your command again

Comment: what changes broke minikube? Also have you tried to re-enable all the modules, restart and start minikube again? I mean like `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

Comment: @Vitalii No luck I tried those commands

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows 10 Home or Enterprise/Pro version? I faced the similar issue when I tried it on Windows 10 Home version and came to know that Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell is not available in Windows 10 home. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v). It worked when I tried it in Enterprise version. Hope this works for you.